# Submitting a partial view via ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a partial view (form) that I am displaying in a modal pop up. On submit it will create a new entry into the Database. This needs to be done via an ajax call. How do I pass all the form fields in the ajax call? I am using MVC4.

I tried $('form').serialize(), but this causes an error Invalid JSON primitive. What am I doing wrong?

```
var dataToSend = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: urlForSaving,
        data: dataToSend,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, status) {
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert('error') }
    });
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Add(SomeModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return Json(new { 
        Success = false,
        Message = "Validation Errors"
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your field values to the object as below and then pass that object to a function which will be called on your required event.

```
 var dataToSend = {
                    fieldname: $("FIELDCLASS OR ID").val();
                  };

  function tocall(){
       $.ajax({
                 url: urlForSaving,
                 data: JSON.stringify(obj:dataToSend),
                 cache: false,
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                 success: function (data, status) {
             },
                 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert('error') }
             });
                   };
```

Comment: I know this can be done. But this is not a cleaner approach. If later I add one more field to my form, I have to make changes in ajax call too. I want to know if this is the only approach or are there better ways?

Comment: @annantDev:This is the best way out of it and if you are really looking for something different then you could do that using   "FormCollection" , just google it out ..but you will have to drop your ajax functionality..hope it helped...

Answer (score 1):

From MVC3 and up I think it's an ideal situation to use Ajax.BeginForm in the partial view (as apposed to Http.BeginForm).  The Ajax version automatically wires up everything for you including the post of the form via ajax.

[MSDN Ajax.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)